# Axios Node.Js GET request with params is undefined

Tags: node.js, reactjs, axios

I am running a react app with nodejs on backend. Whenever I make an axios call without parameters, everything works, but when I try to add paramaters and use them with req.body.variableName, it prints undefined. Printing req.body is just an empty curly brace so somehow my data is not being sent.

React File with axios call

```
getFriendCount(){
    var data = {
        UserID: this.state.UserID,
    }
    console.log(data)
    axios.get("http://localhost:8081/getFriendCount", data).then((response)=>{
        if (response.status >= 400) {
            console.log(response.status);
            throw new Error("Bad response from server");
        } else{
            return response.data[0].friendCount
        }
    }).then((data)=>{
        console.log(data)
        this.setState({count: data})
    })
}
```

serversql.js

```
const HTTP_PORT = process.env.PORT || 8081;
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const app = express();
const urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false });
const cors = require("cors");
const mysql = require('mysql');

app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

const {addNewMemory,getAllMemories, getFriendCount} = require('./db-services.js');

//Database connection...

app.get('/data', getAllMemories);
app.post('/addMemory',urlencodedParser,addNewMemory);
app.get('/getFriendCount',urlencodedParser, getFriendCount);

app.listen(HTTP_PORT, ()=>{console.log("API listening on: " + HTTP_PORT)});
```

db-services.js (req.body.UserID is undefined)

```
module.exports={
  getFriendCount:(req,res) => {
    console.log(req.body)        //empty curly brace
    console.log(req.body.UserID) //undefined
    console.log(req.params)      //empty curly brace
    var sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS friendCount FROM friendship WHERE UserId1 = (?) OR UserId2 = (?)";
    var values = [req.body.UserID, req.body.UserID]
    dbconnection.query(sql, values, function(err,result,fields){
        if(err){
            return res.status(500).send(err);
        } else {
            res.send(result);
        }
    })
},
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the `Axios.get()`, the data represent the params not body data.
So please use the `req.params` instead the body.
And then node you use the route that way.

```
app.get('/getFriendCount/:Id',urlencodedParser, getFriendCount);
```

And then please get the Id using below.

```
console.log(req.params.Id);
```

And then you need to change your API like this.

```
axios.get(`http://localhost:8081/getFriendCount/${this.state.UserID}`)
```

Please try this.

Comment: Does my axios get remain the same?  axios.get("http://localhost:8081/getFriendCount", data)

Comment: No you need to change that.

Answer (score 3):

try the following in the client side

```
  axios.get("http://localhost:8081/getFriendCount", {
          params: {
            UserID: yourUserID
          }
        }).then((response)=>{
        if (response.status >= 400) {
            console.log(response.status);
            throw new Error("Bad response from server");
        } else{
            return response.data[0].friendCount
        }
    }).then((data)=>{
        console.log(data)
        this.setState({count: data})
    })
```

and in the server side instead of using the `body` use the `query` like this `console.log(req.query.UserID)`. Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to send a `body` you can't use a GET method. Only a POST or a PUT method should be used in this case.
GET methods will only take `param` and `query`, where `params can be used like this:

`app.get('/getFriendCount/:id', handler);`

if you would call `/getFriendCount/123`, `req.param.id` would return `123`

and `query` could be used like this:

`/getFriendCount?name=pedro` - req.query would yield `{ name:"pedro" }`

Comment: But what would my axios get be? Would it still be localhost:8081/getFriendCount", data

Comment: @Jasonvilla it really depends on what you prefer. If you want to use the GET method I would suggest you using a param. So your call would be `localhost:8081/getFriendCount/UserID`